# When is it allowed to permute sum and integral for a sequence of measurable functions

Tags: integration, summation, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Consider $\{f_{\nu}\}_{\nu=1}^{\infty}$ such that $\ f_{\nu}\geq0$ and is Lebesgue measurable for every $\nu\in\mathbb{N}$.

When is it allowed to write $\int\sum\limits_{\nu=1}^{\infty}f_{\nu}=\sum\limits_{\nu=1}^{\infty}\int f_{\nu}$ ? When is it not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your $f_\nu$'s are positive by assumption, then the answer to your question is: "always".

This is a consequence of the monotone convergence theorem. For each $n \in \mathbb N$, define $g_n = \sum_{\nu = 1}^n f_\nu$. Then $g_n$ is a monotone-increasing sequence of functions. Applying monotone convergence to $g_n$, we have
$$ \int \sum_{\nu = 1}^\infty f_\nu =  \int \lim_{n \to \infty} g_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int g_n = \sum_{\nu = 1}^\infty \int f_\nu.$$

---

If we drop the assumption that the $f_\nu$'s are positive, then it is possible to find counterexamples. For example, take$$ f_\nu (x) = \begin{cases} -1 & {\rm \ for \ \ }x \in (\nu - 1, \nu) \\ + 1 & {\rm \ for \ \ } x \in (\nu, \nu + 1) \\ 0 & {\rm \ elsewhere}\end{cases}$$
Then
$$ \sum_{\nu = 1}^\infty f_\nu (x) = \begin{cases} -1 & {\rm \ for \ \ }x \in (0, 1) \\ 0 & {\rm \ elsewhere}\end{cases}$$
so
$$ \int \sum_{\nu = 1}^\infty f_\nu = -1.$$
However, for any $\nu$, we have $\int f_\nu = 0$, so
$$ \sum_{\nu = 1}^\infty \int f_\nu = 0.$$

Answer (score 1):

There are several "limit theorems" commonly seen in measure theory.  Dominated convergence.  Monotone convergence.  [Fubini's other theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem_on_differentiation).

As noted in Kenny's answer, the question in your text is covered by the monotone convergence theorem.

Alternatively, your queston is also covered by [Tonelli's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli's_theorem), about integration the product of two measure spaces: here one of the spaces is your integral (I guess the real line with Lebesgue measure) and the other measure space is $\mathbb N$ with counting measure.